# finally { if (inputStream != null) { inputStream.close();

Tags: java, bufferedreader, ioexception

I don't know how to understand this:

```
{
        if (inputStream **!= null**) {
            inputStream.close();
```

from that example:

```
public class CopyLines {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));

        String l;
        while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            outputStream.println(l);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}}
```

inputStream is beeing closed when there is any data provided???

Comment: The `if-statement` is to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What version of Java is that? This looks like pre 1.7 code

Comment: It's from Java documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that whenever the try block is completed (successfully or not) it will try to close the streams (`inputStream` and `outputStream`) in the `finally` block but as the `try` block could fail while creating the instance of `BufferedReader` or `PrintWriter`, you need to check first if it is not `null` otherwise you will get a NPE.

You can consider using [`try-with-resouces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to avoid having to check if `null` and calling `close()` explicitly such that it would simplify your code a lot.

```
try (BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
     PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt")) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: OK. According to Java documentation, do i understand it correctly: readline() reads a line and if it's ended with \n (or anything else proper for this method), then method stops reading and gives back `null`, so JVM handles this process correctly and resources leaks do not occurs eventually? It's possible that during line reading some i/o error occurs and reading is nor properly finished winh `null`, then `finally` block does his job?

Comment: I'm not sure, I get what you mean but indeed it will close the streams whatever happens which will prevent the leaks

Comment: I'm trying to understand how a readLine() is exactly working.

According to JavaDocs i'm not sure if corectly ended readLine(), when there is any line-end indicator readed, is ended with null, which is parsed to JVM or it's null parsed to JVM only when we have a situation when there is an EOF without any line readed...

Comment: Is there a `null` parsed always when a line reading is finished and then closing of a datastream in `finally` block occurs,..? ...so when there is no `null` at end of process the whole process is logical for me (the code in `finally` part). 
Otherwise i don't understand it yet. :/

If there is no `null` at the end of properly readed line and the line itself is not `null` then the process readLine() normally is not closed at all?

Comment: if  readLine returns null what is null at the end is the variable l not the stream

Comment: So...an effect of readLine() is String or null?
Or maybe it's a String and a null "in next line" as an indicator to JVM that the line reading has ended?

Comment: I know what a null is but everything is possible.

Comment: whatever returns readLine null or not, the stream instance will not be null so it will be closed in the finally block as expected

Comment: OK. This explanation satisfies me completely. Thx.

Comment: @DarekK `readLine()` returns a `String` if there is a line available, or null at end of stream. That doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking why this code is in `finally` block, then,

This is simply to ensure that the `inputStream`  and `outputStream` will always be closed, no matter whether the code above encounters or doesn't encounters an exception.

***How is it different.***

The difference is during any exception. If any exception occurs, then instead of simply returning, it will ensure that both the streams are closed before returning the exception to the method that called this method.

bacause java's `finally` block is always executed, unless:

- `System.exit` is called
- or JVM crashes

***This is a common practice*** to close stream, database, or any other similar connections in `finally` blocks. This ensures that the connections are always closed. Because if they aren't in finally block, and system is continuously encountering some or the other `Excpetion` then it will eventually run out of connections.

Comment: no, i'm not interested in finally block. Only `!=null` interests me.

Answer (score 0):

That's just to avoid null pointer exception. The functions are called only when object is not `null`.

In simple words, `close` function is only called when the objects are not null else if you call `close()` on object with null value, you will come across `null pointer exception`.

Interesting thing is the usage of `finally`, which is always called whether there is any exception or not.

Answer (score 0):

When the execution reaches the finally block, it is first checked `inputstream` and `outputstream` are null or not then both the streams are closed to free the resources.

Please refer the link to check about try with finally : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2